# Como fazer para que PrintWriter escreva no arquivo .txt determinada String de uma váriável?

Tags: java

Minha ideia é criar um pequeno banco de dados .txt para salvar os dados de um usuário.

```
public void menuContato(){
        try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("usuarios.txt");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        System.out.println("CRIAÇÃO DE CONTATO");

        System.out.println("Nome: ");
        this.nome = leitor.nextLine();
        pw.print(this.nome);

        System.out.println("Email: ");
        this.email = leitor.nextLine();
        pw.print(this.email);

        System.out.println("Telefone: ");
        this.telefone = leitor.nextLine();
        pw.print(this.telefone);

        Contato usuario = new Contato(nome, email,telefone);
        dados.registraContato(usuario);
         }

        catch(IOException e){
            out.println("ERRO");}


        }
```

O problema é que quando vou usar o **pw.print()** e coloco a variável, o arquivo usuarios.txt é criado, mas nada é escrito no arquivo.

O que posso fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa fechar o pw, pois isso faz com que ele efetivamente escreva no arquivo. Veja que o PrintWriter trabalha com um stream de dados que, por sua vez, é escrito em um arquivo. Executar o comando close() indica que o stream deve ser finalizado e fisicamente escrito em um arquivo.

Acrescente isso ao seu código:

```
} finally {
  pw.close();
}
```